# Fetch data using JSONP

Tags: jsonp

I am using Jsonp to fetch data cross domain.
This is the json.

```
({"cow": [{"count":"951",
"url":"http://www.google.com/"
},]})
```

But the Problem is I am not able to show it on browser.

The code which I am using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
var site ='http://somedomain.com/json.php?url=http://www.google.com/';

$.getJSON(site+"&?callback=?",function(data){
$.each(data.cow, function(i,data){

var div_data = "<a href='"+data.url+"'>"+data.count+"</a>";
$(div_data).appendTo("#getlinks");
});
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
<div id="getlinks">

</div>
```

Where am I wrong.

Answer (score -1):

for starters, you can't have the plain url as a parameter in a GET

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters

use javascript's `encodeURIComponent` function to encode it http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp